Maximum possible number of distinct sets that can occur as diagonal sets for a single choice of $A_1,...,A_n$?
I found this problem in A path to combinatorics for undergraduates. This is problem 9.33.
For a sequence $A_1,...,A_n$ of subsets of $S=\{1,...,n\}$ and a permutation $\pi$ of $S$, we define the diagonal set $D_\pi(A_1,...,A_n)=\{i\in S:i\notin A_{\pi(i)}\}$. What is the maximum possible number of distinct sets that can occur as diagonal sets for a single choice of $A_1,...,A_n$?
I figured that any element that is in every set in the sequence will not be in any diagonal set formed and any element that is not in any set in the sequence will be in any diagonal set formed. Now I don't know how to proceed. Any hint or solution is appreciated. Thank you.

Hi, number of elements in all of thes sets $A_{1}...A_{n}$ can be between 1 and n, and can they represent the same subset or is there some limitation?

Since no limitation has been mentioned in the problem, I guess it is possible that they represent the same subset.

I also don't think it's entirely clear what is denoted by $A_{\pi}$

Fixed. Thank you.

For clarity, I will use $S_n = \{1, \dots, n\}$ to denote the section of the first $n$ positive integers. I will use "$-$" to denote the set-theoretic difference; i.e., $A - B = A \cap B^c$.
Disregarding all restrictions, the total number of diagonal sets that are possible is $2^n$. Of course, not all of these are possible. It is relatively straightforward to see that at least $n$ diagonal sets are not possible.
If all $n$ subsets $A_i$ are distinct, then each $A_i$ itself cannot be a diagonal. We know that $i = \pi (j)$ for some $j \in S_n$. There are then two cases: (1) if $j \in A_i$, then by definition of the diagonal, $j \notin D_\pi = A_i$, and (2) if $j \notin A_i$, then by definition of the diagonal, $j \in D_\pi = A_i$. Both are obvious contradictions.
On the other hand, if $A_i = A_j$ for some $i \ne j$, then consider, for each $k \in S_n$, sets $B_k \subseteq S_n$ such that (1) $B_k - \{k\} = A_i - \{k\}$, and (2) $k \in A_i \Longleftrightarrow k \notin B_k$. You can verify that each $B_k$ is distinct. And, each $B_k$ is not a possible diagonal. We know that $i = \pi (l)$ and $j = \pi (m)$ for some $l \ne m \in S_n$. At least one of $l, m$ must be different from $k$. Then, applying the same argument as above for distinct $A_i$ shows that $B_k$ is not a valid diagonal.
So, the best we can hope to do is $2^n - n$. It is in fact possible to obtain this upper bound if we simply select each $A_i$ to be the singleton set $\{i\}$. As discussed above, the only diagonals that are not possible in this case are the singleton sets. Given any other diagonal $D \subseteq S_n$, consider the following permutation. For any $i \in S_n - D$, let $\pi (i) = i$. Then, order $D$ from least to greatest, and for each $d \in D$, let $\pi (d)$ be the next item in the order if $d \ne \max D$, and $\pi (\max D) = \min D$. (The permutation therefore consists of one nontrivial cycle through all the elements in $D$.) This permutation produces the desired diagonal set, as you can check.
So, the answer is $\boxed{2^n - n}$.

If it helps, here is the OEIS sequence: https://oeis.org/A000325.
